# Why is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,U) = E[XU]=0$?

Tags: linear-regression, regression-analysis

In my econometric course, when talking about zero conditional mean in the context of simple linear regression $E[U \mid X]=0$, it says $\operatorname{Cov}(X,U) = E[XU]=0$ on lecture slides.

Why is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,U) = E[XU]=0$?

X is the independent variable; U is the error term.

Comment: It is best to ask the lecturer, rather than us.

Comment: I mistakenly interchanged the role of $X$ and $U$ but the idea remains the same: $E[U] = E[E[U\mid X]] = 0$ and $E[UX] = E[E[U\mid X]X] = 0$.

Comment: @SangchulLee How do you get $Cov(X,U)$ into your argument? Is it only applicable for the case when both $Cov(X,U)$ and $E[XU]$ are 0?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what you are asking. $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)$ is defined by $E[(X-EX)(Y-EY)]$ which is the same as $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$. The above computation shows that if $E[U\mid X] = 0$ then both $E[UX] = 0$ and $E[U]E[X] = 0$ hold.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry about that. Just added it.

Answer (score 2):

As @SangchulLee commented, if you have zero conditional mean then you consequently have zero covariance.

> If we may *assume* $\mathsf E(U\mid X)=0$, therefore:
>
> $\begin{align}\mathsf {Cov}(X,U)&=\mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))(U-\mathsf E(U))) &&\textsf{by Definition} \\ &= \mathsf E(\,XU-X\,\mathsf E(U)-\mathsf E(X)\,U+\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(U)\,) &&\textsf{by Distribution} \\ &= \mathsf E(XU)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(U)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(U)+\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(U)&&\textsf{by Linearity of Expectation} \\ &=\mathsf E(XU)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(U) &&\textsf{by Algebraic simplification} \\ &= \mathsf E(XU)-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(\mathsf E(U\mid X)) &&\textsf{by Law of Total Expectation} \\ &= \mathsf E(XU) - \mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(0) && \textsf{by the Assumption} \\ &= \mathsf E(XU) && \textsf{by Definition of Zero} \\[2ex] &= \mathsf E(\mathsf E(XU\mid X)) &&\textsf{by Law of Total Expectation} \\ &= \mathsf E(X\,\mathsf E(U\mid X)) &&\textsf{by Linearity of Expectation} \\ &= \mathsf E(X\cdot 0) &&\textsf{by the Assumption} \\ &= 0 &&\textsf{by Definition of Zero}
> \end{align}$

Comment: Even if one does not have $\operatorname E(U\mid X) =0,$ one still has $\operatorname{cov}(X,U)=0$ if the method of estimation is least squares. For example, let the independent variable $X$ take on the values $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ each with equal probability, and let $Y=X^2,$ and find the best-fitting line $Y=aX+b,$ choosing $a$ and $b$ by minimizing $\operatorname E((Y-(aX+b))^2) = \operatorname E(U^2).$ Then one has $\operatorname{cov}(X,U)=0$ even though $\operatorname E(U\mid X) \ne 0.$ (Maybe I'll post a separate answer.) $\qquad$

Comment: Hi, could I ask how you got from the fourth last line, E(E(XU|X)) to the third last line, E(XE(U|X))? I have not learnt linearity of expectation in the context of conditional expectation and I can't seem to figure this out or find a resource that explains this step of the proof, so would really appreciate your detailed advice/explanation on this!

Comment: Basically @Charlz97 $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf E(XU\mid X))&=\int\int xu~p(\mathsf du\mid x)~p(\mathsf d x)\\&=\int x\int u~p(\mathrm du\mid x)~p(\mathrm d x)\\&=\mathsf E(X~\mathsf E(U\mid X))\end{align}$$